winAPI hooking trampoline does not work properly
I'm trying to hook a winAPI function using a trampoline function, but it does not work.
Can some one spot the problem?
My code is using a patch with a jmp instruction to a trampoline function. The trampoline function  has the original bytes of the winAPI function, and then a jmp instruction to the original function after the patch.
When running the program, I do get the output
"Hooked MessageBoxA called!", that means the function does get hooked, but I don't see the msg box.
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

struct HookedFunction {
    FARPROC functionOriginalAddress;
    BYTE functionOriginalBytes[12];
    SIZE_T bytesRead;
    SIZE_T bytesWritten;
    int modifyTimes;
};

HookedFunction* MessageBoxAStruct;
LPVOID trampolineAddress;

// Define the hooked MessageBoxA function
int WINAPI HookedMessageBoxA(HWND hWnd, LPCSTR lpText, LPCSTR lpCaption, UINT uType) {
    // Custom behavior
    std::cout << "Hooked MessageBoxA called!" << std::endl;

    // Call the original MessageBoxA using the trampoline
    auto trampoline = (decltype(&MessageBoxA))trampolineAddress;
    return trampoline(hWnd, lpText, lpCaption, uType);
}

void HookMessageBoxA() {
    printf("hooking...\n");

    MessageBoxAStruct = new HookedFunction;
    MessageBoxAStruct->bytesRead = 0;
    MessageBoxAStruct->bytesWritten = 0;

    // Get the handle to user32.dll (if it's already loaded)
    HMODULE library = GetModuleHandle(L"user32.dll");
    if (library == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Handle error - couldn't get the address: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (MessageBoxAStruct->modifyTimes != 1)
    {
        printf("hooking...\n");

        FARPROC MessageBoxAAddress = GetProcAddress(library, "MessageBoxA");
        // Check if the address is valid
        if (MessageBoxAAddress == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Failed to get address of MessageBoxA: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalAddress = MessageBoxAAddress;
        // Save the first 12 bytes of the original MessageBoxA function - will need for unhooking
        if (!ReadProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), MessageBoxAAddress, MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes, sizeof(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes), &MessageBoxAStruct->bytesRead)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to read original bytes of MessageBoxA: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        MessageBoxAStruct->modifyTimes = 1;

        // Allocate memory for the trampoline function
        trampolineAddress = VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes) + 14, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
        if (trampolineAddress == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Failed to allocate memory for the trampoline: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Copy original bytes to the trampoline
        if (!WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), trampolineAddress, MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes, sizeof(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes), &MessageBoxAStruct->bytesWritten)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to write trampoline: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        // Add a jump from the trampoline back to the original function's next instruction
        DWORD64 jumpBackAddress = (DWORD64)MessageBoxAAddress + sizeof(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes);
        unsigned char jumpBackPatch[] = {
            0x48, 0xb8,              // mov rax,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // <address to jump back to>
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,  // <address to jump back to>
            0xFF, 0xE0               // jmp rax
        };
        *(DWORD64*)&jumpBackPatch[2] = jumpBackAddress;

        if (!WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)((DWORD64)trampolineAddress + sizeof(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalBytes)), jumpBackPatch, sizeof(jumpBackPatch), &MessageBoxAStruct->bytesWritten)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to write jump back in trampoline: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Create a patch "mov rax, <address of new MessageBoxA>; jmp rax"
    unsigned char patch[] = {
        0x48, 0xb8,             // mov rax,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // <address of hook>
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // <address of hook>
        0xFF, 0xE0              // jmp rax
    };
    *(DWORD64*)&patch[2] = (DWORD64)HookedMessageBoxA;



    // Change memory protection to allow writing
    DWORD oldProtect;
    if (!VirtualProtect(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalAddress, sizeof(patch), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to change memory protection: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess(), (LPVOID)MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalAddress, patch, sizeof(patch), &MessageBoxAStruct->bytesWritten)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to write patch: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Restore original memory protection
    if (!VirtualProtect(MessageBoxAStruct->functionOriginalAddress, sizeof(patch), oldProtect, &oldProtect)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to restore memory protection: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    printf("Hooked successfully\n");
    std::cout << "finished hooking...\n\n" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    HookMessageBoxA();
    // Example call to the hooked function
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Test", "Test", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}


One doesn't just moves 12 bytes of code into another location and slaps rax-trampling jump to stitch it. This couldn't possibly reliably work.

You don't even know these 12 bytes form complete instructions. Indeed, first 3 instructions take 14 bytes in my version of user32.dll. As such, your mov rax would've been eaten as a part of the third instruction.
You don't know these moved instruction do not change code flow. For all we know, the very first instruction might be a jump or call somewhere else (and it won't work since these are usually pc-relative and you have relocated it)
More generally, you don't know whether any of relocated instructions are pc-relative. Especially on x64 this is a possibility. Indeed, one of the instruction in my version is! It won't work when relocated.
Finally, you trample over rax. One of the relocated instructions might've written to it and you'd destroyed that value.

There's a reason hooking libraries are a thing. Hooking is not such a simple thing to do.
Also, don't restrict yourself to printf-style debugging! Debuggers are a thing now, and they are quite powerful. As a minimum, one would expect you to first check MessageBoxA original code, and your resulting trampoline, and probably to single step through it and see if it works; and only then run and ask questions to SO. If you did so, I suspect you'd immediately see your trampoline looks nothing like the original code+jmp.

thank you for your help. what will you suggest me to do so?

If you just want to hook some functions, find a good library to do so. If you really-really want to do it yourself, find yourself a good tutorial (and an assembler/disassembler engine because you'd need to do some non-trivial code modifications). See e.g. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1252212/PolyHook-2-Cplusplus17-x86-x64-Hooking-Library - that's a library; also this is not a tutorial but the PolyHook v1 article covers all the points I made in greater detail, and v2 article covers some extra difficulties you might run into.
